# Laravel: Why can't I use an 'Orders' directory within App\Controllers

Tags: laravel, namespaces, phpstorm

I was able to create the directory, but when I tried to create the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Orders;` PHP Storm was showing errors. I could namespace with any other directory name that I tried within \Controllers except for \Orders.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: What errors were being shown?

Comment: PHP Storm would throw the error `Unexpected Identifier` on the 'O' of Order, then the rest of the word would be syntax highlighted as if it were a constant. I could use just about any other 'O' word, I remember trying 'OpenField' and it let me name it like that. I probably shouldn't have even noted this as a Laravel problem, as now I'm guessing it's probably just a PHP Storm error.